# Defs elements redefinition in couple of places

Tags: svg

Following code produces two different results in Chrome (Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)) and Firefox (50.1.0). Basically Chrome allows you to have same id of linear gradients in two different svgs, but Firefox doesn't - there will be only one linear gradient defined. See code snippet below.

Which behaviour is correct?

```html
<svg id='1'>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient x1="-1.11022302e-14%" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%" id="linearGradient-1">
      <stop stop-color="red" offset="0%"></stop>
      <stop stop-color="orange" offset="100%"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)"></rect>
</svg>

<svg id='2'>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient x1="50.0008675%" y1="-42.2278548%" x2="50.0008675%" y2="82.3571634%" id="linearGradient-1">
      <stop stop-color="blue" offset="0%"></stop>
      <stop stop-color="green" offset="100%"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate `id` values are illegal, and the behaviour of the browser when that happens is undefined.  So there is no "correct" behaviour.